# getting all static variables in a class into array/list

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Bit of a wierd requirement.

```
public class DummyClass{
   public static final DummyClass var1;
   public static final DummyClass var2;
   public static final DummyClass var3;
    .
    .
    .
   public static final DummyClass var100;
}
```

Now from outside of this class can we pool this var's into a single array or list, so that I can iterate over them? Like if i do something like

```
List<DummyClass> dummyList = *some op*; //I want value of some op.
```

I should be able to access var1...var100

Comment: I cannot change the source of DummyClass.

Comment: I would look into using reflection.

Comment: Can you make it an enum?

Comment: @Tom As I said, I do not have access to source file.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You could use reflection:

```
Field[] fields = DummyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
for (Field f : fields) {
    if (Modifier.isStatic(f.getModifiers()) && isRightName(f.getName())) {
        doWhatever(f);
    } 
}
```

Comment: @Chandra Please mark an aswer correct, if you think its correct solution

Comment: @Cameron I don't find any isRghtName() method in the Modifier class.

Comment: @NarutoUzumaki: It's pseudocode. `isRightName` is meant to signify user code that decides if the field name is interesting. Note that this snippet does not call `Modifier.isRightName`; it's just `isRightName`.

Comment: Should the `&&` really be inside the `isStatic`-method? If so there are still  two `)` missing in the if statement.

Comment: @CameronSkinner how I can make it to a genenal util method for all this kind of Classes, I tried pass DummyClass as a parameter that argument is a  type of class? but not worked. thx.     code is something like:  `public void printAllProps(Class c) { }`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a class with constants and want to get the actual values of your java constant you can do following:

```
   List<String> constantValues = Arrays.stream(DummyClass.class.getDeclaredFields())
      .filter(field -> Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers()))
      .map(field -> {
        try {
          return (String) field.get(DummyClass.class);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
          throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
      })
      .filter(name -> ! name.equals("NOT_NEEDED_CONSTANT") // filter out if needed 
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```