# Get all static variables of a class without reflection

Tags: java

We have an exception Class A with a few fault codes defined as `public static final` and it is referenced in many files (more than 100) in our source code. 
We want all these fault codes in Class B for some processing.

Currently we have implemented a method called `getFaultCodes()` in Class A to build a list of fault codes and return the same. The problem with this approach is that whenever an fault code is introduced, it has to be added in `getFaultCode` method as well. This is error prone, as a user may forget to add the new code to the method.

Moving these fault codes under an `enum` requires changes in many files all over the source code, so we don't want do this.

```
class ExceptionA  {
   public static final String faultCode1 = "CODE1";
   public static final String faultCode2 = "CODE1";
   public static final String faultCode3 = "CODE1";

   List<String> getFaultCodes(){
         list.add(faultCode1);
         ......
         return list;
   }
}
```

We are thinking about using reflection, but I'm posting in this forum just to check if there is a better solution. Please provide your suggestion to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466743/getting-all-static-variables-in-a-class-into-array-list

Comment: @cyber_rookie that one uses reflection though :P

Comment: i won't call it a duplicate as the OP knows about reflection as solution. He asks for another one

Comment: It's impossible w/o reflection.

Comment: Why not keep this class as wrapper and use enum internally?

Comment: I don't think it can be done without reflection :D and yes, its not a duplicate, my bad.

Comment: There are a lot of folks on SO with an itchy trigger finger regarding duplicates.  Is there a competition to be the first one to post it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified code code like below:

```
class ExceptionA  {

   public enum codes {
        CODE1("CODE1"),
        CODE2("CODE2"),
        CODE3("CODE3"),

       private String code;

      codes(String code){
          this.code = code;
      }

      public String getCode() {
          return this.code;
      }  
   }
   public static final String faultCode1 = code.CODE1;
   public static final String faultCode2 = code.CODE2;
   public static final String faultCode3 = code.CODE3;

}
```

So that I need not to change the variables occurrences "faultCode" in the source code, I can access the list of fault codes from other class.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can go through an interface:

```
public interface FaultCodeProvider
{
    String getFaultCode();
}
```

Then have your enums implement it:

```
public enum DefaultFaultCodes
    implements FaultCodeProvider
{
    FAULT1("text for fault 1"),
    // etc
    ;

    private final String value;

    DefaultFaultCodes(final String value)
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String getFaultCode()
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Collecting them from the enum is then as easy as cycling through the enum's `values()`.

Comment: The interface isn't actually part of your solution here... you're not using it for anything...

Comment: So? You can do that without the interface.

Comment: @immibis not if the fault text contains anything invalid in a Java identifier

Comment: @fge Thanks for your suggestion. Are you suggesting to change the ExcpetionA class to enum? If so I can't because class ExceptionA is used to instantiate in the our code.

Comment: @fge So why do you need the interface? Remove `public interface FaultCodeProvider {...}`, remove `implements FaultCodeProvider`, and remove `@Override`.