# Copy all exif tags from one jpeg to another

Tags: android, exif, android-exifinterface

I am trying to figure out the best way to copy all exif tags from one JEPG to another.  Looks like ExifInterface (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface) is my best bet.

However,

1. There is no way to grab all tags contained in one JPEG.
2. The full list of all tags in ExifInterface class is private/protected.

Is there a better option than adding all ~100 tag names to my class?  I don't really want to modify code every time I discover that an Android camera is adding a new exif tag that I did not account for.

Comment: Are you able to do this kind of thing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4466743/getting-all-static-variables-in-a-class-into-array-list

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no such way to do that, except maybe using reflection to access the private attributes in the `ExifInterface` class. However, that's discouraged since of course, the implementation may break in future releases. For brevity I wrote up how that may be done below.

That said, you may be able to use something like *Apache Sanslean* to do what you're looking for: http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/copying-exif-metadata-using-sanselan/. However, I did not try it myself so I couldn't say more

### Using reflection

Looking at the `ExifInterface` [source](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/exifinterface/exifinterface/1.2.0-source/androidx/exifinterface/media/ExifInterface.java.html), it seems that there is no "standard" way to obtain all tags. However, you can use reflection to read the `mAttributes` map for all keys (Although that's much less safe, but a last resort). Something like this should work (Java):

```java
Field f = obj.getClass().getDeclaredField("mAttributes");
f.setAccessible(true);
HashMap<String, ExifAttribute>[] attributes = (HashMap<String, ExifAttribute>[]) f.get(obj);
```

Then, you can use reflection in the same way to access a destintation `ExifInterface` and copy all fields to it.

Note that I looked at the AndroidX version of `ExifInterface`, which is a superset of the original class and the recommended one to use, but the same should apply otherwise.